# Continious Polling issue node+express+soket.io

Tags: node.js, laravel-5, socket.io

Getting continuously http://localhost:8890/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1525342978802-2 get requests

Client : socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890')

Server: var app = require('express')();

var server = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(8890);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

```
console.log(socket['id'] + "  client connected");
```

});

Any help highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you are getting a 404 error from these calls, 2 things:

1. Have you imported socket.io on client?

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>`

or just

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

2. Have you run **npm install** after adding express and socket.io references on package.json?

Can you write the full code (client at least)?

Comment: Actually it was socket version issue, and I already have resolved by myself.